# Describe the shape of projection of vertices (vector positions of a cube) onto a 2D plane from a source (position vector)?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, mathematical-physics, plane-geometry

I am having trouble with this. I can manually calculate every single projection point onto the z=0 plane from deriving vector equations to get to the z plane for each vertices. From this I can then plot all these coordinates to find the shape. Is there a better/faster method as this question shouldn't take long.
Many thanks

[The question for context is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDYIJ.jpg)
[Here is my method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Oc8.jpg)

Comment: The fact that this is a cube parallel to the projection plane gives it some simplifying properties. But you still have to compute _some_ points. If you wrote out your own methods in detail for at least one point, perhaps someone would notice where you could reduce the effort.

Comment: Hi David, I have updated the post with my method shown. I create vectors between the light source and each verticy and then extrapolate them to the plane z=0 to get the points of projection.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that people here tend not to like reading the math from photographs, especially if the original is handwritten. You can look at other questions that were highly rated and got good answers to see how people format questions to get those kinds of answers. You may decide it's not worth the effort. If you want to continue, step 1 is to learn some MathJax: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 0):

You should get a hexagon a rectangle or a square.

$(\frac 14, \frac 54), (\frac 14, \frac 94),(\frac 54, \frac 54),(\frac 54, \frac 94), (-\frac 12, \frac 32),(-\frac 12, \frac 52),(\frac 32, \frac 52),(\frac 12, \frac 32)$

How do you get these.

$P_n - \lambda L$ and find $\lambda$ such that the $z$ component equals $0.$

[image]

Comment: I ended up with a pattern of https://imgur.com/a/XG2rsX9

Comment: That doesn't look like a cube.